# Cannot catch submit event from a form inside a modal - getting $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, webpack, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a scheduler / roster application in the Symfony 5 framework, with webpack behind it, together with Jquery to handle (amongst others) user based actions (like clicking on a cell).

When the user clicks on a cell, a modal pops up with in that modal a form with the data linked to that cell. I would like to catch the submit of the form included in the modal, and then fire a AJAX call to the backend so the data is stored.

See below the current JQUERY code i have so far.
I currently catch the shown.bs.modal event. After that i want to surpres the default submit action, and replace it with my own.

However, when i try to do it, i'm getting the infamous "$ is not a function" error.

I have tried it several ways (even including the javascript inside the modal itself), but even here it fails. I'm now kind of stuck.

Does anyone know what i have done wrong?

I even tried the jquery.noconflict() method in the function, but this also failed miserably.

```js
require('../css/app.css');
require('../css/global.scss');
require('bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css');
require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css');

// Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to require it.
const $ = require('jquery');
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');

require('bootstrap');
require('bootstrap-datepicker');

import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';

import dt from 'datatables.net';
import dtbs4 from 'datatables.net-bs4';
import dtbs4fh from 'datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4';
import dtbs4sel from 'datatables.net-select-bs4';

var moment = require('moment');
moment().format();
Routing.setRoutingData(routes);

$( document ).ready(function() {

    var table = $("#calendarSchedule").DataTable({
        select: {
            style: 'os',
            items: 'cell',
            info: false
        }
    });
    jQuery.noConflict(); 
    //table.on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        //if ( type === 'cell' ) {
            var clickDate = undefined;
            var dt = undefined;
            var cell = undefined;
            var colIndex = undefined;

            $('.dataTable').on('click', 'tbody td div', function() {

            var x = event.clientX;
            var y = event.clientY;
            var w = $(window).width();

            dt = $('#YearMonth').text();
            clickDate = this.id;
            console.log(clickDate);

            if(this.id.indexOf("-")== -1){
                var url = Routing.generate('schedule_viewModal', { id: this.id });
                $("#scheduleModal").load(url);
                $("#scheduleModal").find('schedule_entry').trigger('reset');
                var element = document.getElementById("scheduleModal");

                if(x + 500 > w){
                    element.style.left = w - 500 + "px";  
                } else {
                    element.style.left = x + "px";
                }        

                element.style.top = y + "px";
                $("#scheduleModal").modal('show');
            } else {
                var dayType = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];
                console.log(dayType);
                var url = Routing.generate('schedule_createModal', { dt: clickDate, type: dayType });
                $("#scheduleModal").load(url);
                $("#scheduleModal").find('schedule_entry').trigger('reset');
                var element = document.getElementById("scheduleModal");

                if(x + 500 > w){
                  element.style.left = w - 500 + "px";  
                } else {
                  element.style.left = x + "px";
                }        
                element.width = 250 + "px";
                element.height = 250 + "px";
                element.style.top = y + "px";
                $("#scheduleModal").modal('show');

                if($(this).find("div").length == 0){
                    var x = event.clientX;
                    var y = event.clientY;
                    var w = $(window).width();
                }
              };
        });

     $('#scheduleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

            $('.js-new-form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            route = '{{ path("schedule_jsonNew") }}';
            var dt = document.getElementById('schedule_entry_ScheduleDate').value;
            var tp = document.getElementById('schedule_entry_ScheduleType').value;
            var cat = document.getElementById('schedule_entry_Category').value;
            var emp = document.getElementById('schedule_entry_Employee').value;

            var entry = {date: dt, type: tp, category: cat, employee: emp};
            var data = JSON.stringify(entry);
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url: route,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                async: true,
                success: function () {
                    console.log('succes');
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('fail');
                    location.reload();
                },

            })
        });
        var $=jQuery.noConflict();
        $('#btnClose').on('click', function(e){
            //location.reload();
        });
        $(".js-close-modal").click(function(){
            console.log("bla");
          $(".modal").removeClass("visible");
        });
});   

});
```

Below is the twig template of the modal itself:

```
{# empty Twig template #}
{% trans_default_domain 'messages' %}

  <div class="modal__header">
      {% trans %}schedule.new{% endtrans %}
  </div>    
        <div class="container-fluid">


            {{ form_start(form,  {
                'attr': {
                'class': 'js-new-form',
                'id': 'js-new-form' }})}}

                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px" class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ form_label(form.ScheduleDate, 'schedule.ScheduleDate'|trans({}, 'messages')) }}
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ form_widget(form.ScheduleDate) }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px" class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ form_label(form.ScheduleType, 'schedule.ScheduleType'|trans({}, 'messages')) }}
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ form_widget(form.ScheduleType) }}
                    </div>
                </div>    
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px" class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{   'schedule.scheduleCategory'|trans({}, 'messages') }}
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ form_widget(form.scheduleCategory) }}
                     </div>     
                </div>
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px" class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{   'schedule.scheduleEmployee'|trans({}, 'messages') }}
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ form_widget(form.scheduleEmployee) }}
                     </div>     
                </div>          
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px" class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ form_errors ( form ) }} 
                     </div>     
                </div>        
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px" class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnClose">Close</button>
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ form_widget(form.schedulesave) }}
                     </div>     
                </div>     

            {{ form_end(form) }}


    </div>
```

Comment: I don't know Symfony, but according to this article https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-applications.html you should resolve it by calling `autoProvidejQuery()` from your `webpack.config.js`... And I have no idea what it means ... I can't help you further, the best I can do is link the guide :) greetings

Comment: This seems like an obvious question but is jquery installed or imported correctly?

Comment: @gillharman, fair question, but it is installed ;-)

Comment: @Baro, unfortunately this wan't the solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: Why are you doing `jQuery.noConflict();` inside of document ready???

Comment: @epascarello, because the jquery was conflicting with the datatables stuff as i can remember.I can remove it though?

Comment: @epascarello, removed the jQuery.noConflict() also

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendation:**

I think issue with binding. You can remove binding out of `.on('shown.bs.modal'`. Since jquery take care of binding out of box. and current code is like binding again and again. can be avoided.

```
 $('#scheduleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

    })
      $('.js-new-form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            route = '{{ path("schedule_jsonNew") }}';
            var dt = document.getElementById('schedule_entry_ScheduleDate').value;
            var tp = document.getElementById('schedule_entry_ScheduleType').value;
            var cat = document.getElementById('schedule_entry_Category').value;
            var emp = document.getElementById('schedule_entry_Employee').value;

            var entry = {date: dt, type: tp, category: cat, employee: emp};
            var data = JSON.stringify(entry);
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url: route,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                async: true,
                success: function () {
                    console.log('succes');
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('fail');
                    location.reload();
                },

            })
        });
        var $=jQuery.noConflict();
        $('#btnClose').on('click', function(e){
            //location.reload();
        });
        $(".js-close-modal").click(function(){
            console.log("bla");
          $(".modal").removeClass("visible");
        });
```

Comment: Tried this one also, to no avail. Either i am getting jQuery not defined, or $ is not a function.

Comment: why u need ?? var $=jQuery.noConflict(); remove and try

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work also. I have now moved the code towards the webpack file, and even then the function isn't hit. Seems that it doesn't catch the submit event at all.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, is the one i'm getting. Does the modal take over the included jquery from the main page by any chance? If not, that could explain the error (jquery not being available inside the modal)